# Overwrite multi-classed css with single class css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am using two separate CSS files with media queries to achieve different styles based on the screen size of the viewer. I have the following lines in my desktop css file:

Desktop CSS:

```
.labelContainer .labelText.labelText_xl {
  width: 155px;
}

.labelContainer .labelText.labelText_big {
  width: 135px;
}

.labelContainer .labelText.labelText_med {
  width: 105px;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve, that when the Mobile css version kicks in, indifferent of the labelText_size class the labelText should take up all the width it can. If I copy the above three rules, and change the width to 100% in each of them, this works just as intended. But if I try to do the following

```
.labelContainer .labelText {
  width: 100%;
  height: 32px;
}
```

only the height gets changed, and the width stays the same.

I presume this is because the more exact the rule, the higher priority it has, **but isn't there a way to tell CSS, that no matter what other classes the DOM element has, apply the desired rule?**

Because if I define like 20 different size styles for my labels, I would now have to define the same 20 different size styles in my mobile css too, instead of using a single rule, that overwrites the rest.

**EDIT:** I know I can achieve the desired result with marking the rule as important, but I would rather not do that, because I don't think that setting something as important is a good practice in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
.labelContainer .labelText[class*="labelText_"] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, accepting this in a few minutes, thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

You could add any class only for mobile devices on `<html>` or `<body>` and use it in your mobile CSS version. For example:

```
.mobile .labelContainer .labelText {
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
}
```